# Creating Azure Data Factory Linked Service with Terraform Creates Link in Live Mode

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-adf

When I create a linked service in Azure Data Factory (ADF) for Databricks with terraform (using azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_databricks) the linked service shows up only in live mode.

How can I make the linked service available in GIT mode where all the other ADF pipeline configurations are stored?

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.97.0"
    }
    databricks = {
      source = "databrickslabs/databricks"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "databricks" {
  host          = azurerm_databricks_workspace.this.workspace_url
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "this" {
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "this" {
  name                = "myadf-9182371362"
  resource_group_name = "testrg"
  location            = "East US"

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }       

  vsts_configuration {
      account_name    = "mydevopsorg"
      branch_name     = "main"
      project_name    = "adftest"
      repository_name = "adftest"
      root_folder     = "/adf/"
      tenant_id       = data.azurerm_client_config.this.tenant_id
  }

}

resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "this" {
  name                 = "mydbworkspace"
  resource_group_name = "testrg"
  location            = "East US"
  sku                  = "standard"

}

data "databricks_node_type" "smallest" {
  local_disk = true

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_databricks_workspace.this
  ]
}

data "databricks_spark_version" "latest_lts" {
  long_term_support = true

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_databricks_workspace.this
  ]
}

resource "databricks_cluster" "this" {
  cluster_name = "Single Node"
  spark_version = data.databricks_spark_version.latest_lts.id
  node_type_id  = data.databricks_node_type.smallest.id
  autotermination_minutes = 20

  spark_conf = {
    "spark.databricks.cluster.profile" : "singleNode"
    "spark.master" : "local[*]"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_databricks_workspace.this
  ]

  custom_tags = {
    "ResourceClass" = "SingleNode"
  }
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "this" {
  name = "testrg"
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_resource_group.this.id 
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"  
  principal_id         = azurerm_data_factory.this.identity[0].principal_id
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_databricks" "msi_linked" {
  name                = "ADBLinkedServiceViaMSI"
  data_factory_id     = azurerm_data_factory.this.id
  resource_group_name = "testrg"
  description         = "ADB Linked Service via MSI"
  adb_domain          = "https://${azurerm_databricks_workspace.this.workspace_url}"

  existing_cluster_id = databricks_cluster.this.id
  msi_work_space_resource_id = azurerm_databricks_workspace.this.id
}
```

result in git mode
[image: Git mode]

result in live mode
[image: live mode]

Comment: Is this the entire Terraform code?

Comment: Marko, I updated the code, now it's a complete example

Comment: Ok, so there are no issues with this?

Comment: Terraform creates the resources but the created linked service (Databricks connection) is in the live mode of data factory. The ADF pipeline configurations are stored and git and ADF is connected to Git. Now I have the linked service in live mode and the pipelines in git mode. But I need both in the same mode to run the pipeline using the linked service.

Answer (score 0):

I think when in GIT mode, all the linked service definitions, global parameters etc. are read from the JSON files found in the GIT branch.

So I assume this is expected behaviour.